# A value error appears when I use a formula in a pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I've tried to add a (calculated field) in a pivot table to calculate an average. When I write the formula which is (=SUM("Box Office Revenue ($)")/count("Box Office Revenue ($)")), I get a
*Value Error* with a message telling me that the parameter of sum function isn't numeric.

I made sure that I formatted this parameter as numeric in the original dataset and also in the pivot table.

[a pic of the pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrUzX.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look right to me: `(=SUM("Box Office Revenue ($)")/count("Box Office Revenue ($)"))` The parenthesis don't make sense. And you seem to be putting named ranges in quotes (which makes them strings instead of named ranges).

Adding further confusion, you seem to have included parentheses in the actual name of a named range: `Box Office Revenue ($)`.

If that *is*, in fact, the name of a named range, try this:

`=SUM(Box Office Revenue ($))/COUNT(Box Office Revenue ($))`

Maybe you aren't referencing named ranges but headers used as database tags. In that case, try this version *with* quotes:

`=SUM("Box Office Revenue ($)")/COUNT("Box Office Revenue ($)")`

... or with single quotes:

`=SUM('Box Office Revenue ($)')/COUNT('Box Office Revenue ($)')`

If neither of those work, consider sharing a link to your spreadsheet or a copy of it. That may be the only way for those here to figure out what you're trying to do and why it isn't working for you.

---

**Note:** Single quotes around header from original table is what turned out to work inside a pivot table's custom calculation formula field.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried this formula ( =SUM(Box Office Revenue ($))/COUNT(Box Office Revenue ($))  )  but I got an error called " formula parse "  so I think it needs quotes.  Also, I tried the second version but it gave me the Value error telling me that I'm trying to sum strings.

This is a link for my spreadsheet, and it's okay to edit.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IsIFOBdhBnnTtRigKWtCfJbLHhbbdylhwLfe_fS0efA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is hard to know how to advise you unless you indicate what you *expect* the output to be. As written, `=SUM( )/COUNT( )` would return the same amount as the "AVERAGE <10M ($)" column. However, what I did see is that you need to surround header names in *single quotes* (e.g., `'Box Office Revenue ($)'`) within the Pivot Table's custom formula field. At least that bit of information may get you closer to your goal.

Comment: You're right, I was trying to get the average which can be calculated by other ways. But I was trying to understand why this manual formula not working as a troubleshooting practice. thank you for your time, your advice solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

FYI The formula with single quote symbols worked. Regular quotation marks apparently don't work in this kind of situation.

```
=sum('Box Office Revenue ($)')/count('Box Office Revenue ($)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I entered only the ***/COUNT('Box Office Revenue ($))*** was only returning 1 for each row, which is incorrect, because it should return 10,8,11,20 and 8 respectively.

I re-entered it until it returned the correct values for each row, and then added the ***=SUM('Box Office Revenue($)')*** to the beginning of the calculation, which then provided the correct output for the formula =SUM('Box Office Revenue ($)')/COUNT('Box Office Revenue ($)').
Cheers!